# Javascript Ctrl + Click not working in Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a function, which is supposed to run when clicking an input of type checkbox...

```
$.fn.ctrlSelectable = function() {
    var lastChecked,
        $boxes = this;

    $boxes.click(function(evt) {
        console.log("clicked")

        if(!lastChecked) {
            lastChecked = this;
            return;
        }

        if(evt.ctrlKey) {
            var start = $boxes.index(this),
                end = $boxes.index(lastChecked);
            $boxes.slice(Math.min(start, end), Math.max(start, end) + 1)
                .prop('checked', lastChecked.checked)
                .trigger('change');
        }

        lastChecked = this;
    });
};
$("form").find('input[type="checkbox"]').ctrlSelectable();
```

The function works in IE, Google, and probably others, but does NOT work in Firefox. When I do not hold Ctrl and simply click on a checkbox, the `console.log("clicked")` fires off, but when I hold control, it does not do anything. Can anyone provide me some guidance as to why this would be happening or how I can fix it?

Thank you.

Comment: On which OS ? Don't know about others, but in macOS, ctrl+click is a right click which will trigger `mousedown` + `contextmenu` events but not a `click` one.

Comment: Windows. Thanks for the tip though, I will keep that in mind in case I ever have to use a Mac.

Comment: Still, try to attach your handler on mousedown event to see if you get something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After much dismay, I've found that there is nothing wrong with this function, rather that Firefox does not pass click events from label elements to their target input fields... Since I am using custom looking checkboxes, the actual input element is hidden, while the label is visible and targets the checkbox.